# Special Character in Subject field of discussion forum

Tags: discussion-board

I am creating a new discussion, in the subject when i enter "Portal Discussion?" then it gives error that special character is not allowed. But i want to use the "?" in the subject at the time of creation.

After creating the discussion i can edit the same thing with special characters, then why SharePoint is not allowing to enter special character at the time of creation.

Comment: Most probably it's trying to create an url part with included '?', which is invalid. But after changing the subject, url stays the same and therefore check for invalid path characters is skipped.

Comment: Have you tried to use HTML Encoding for your special characters?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i am using out of box functionality of Discussion Board. I had not written any code to display the discussion. While creating the discussion it does not take special character in subject but after discussion is created i can add the special character in subject. Why SharePoint is not allowing me to add special character at the time of creation.

Comment: SharePoint 2013 allows me to create a discussion with "Portal Discussion?" as subject. Are you using an earlier version ?

Comment: The only restriction i could find for the Subject text in SP 2013 is that it can't end with ".com".

Comment: and ".com?" also :)